# Leonardo with hm-10 doesn't work

Tags: arduino-leonardo, ble

I have a hm-10 module attached to Arduino Leonardo board, I'm using a bluetooth terminal app to send some text.

The problem is I can send data from the Serial monitor to my phone but when I send from my phone, there is no output in the serial monitor.

It works fine if I test it on Arduino Uno.
I'm struggling with something that should be simple.

Can someone please help me?

Here is my code:-

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 

SoftwareSerial BTSerial(4, 5); 

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);            
  Serial.println("Hello!");      
  BTSerial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  while (BTSerial.available()){ 
    byte data = BTSerial.read();
    Serial.write(data);
  }  

  while (Serial.available()){
    byte data = Serial.read();
    BTSerial.write(data); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Leonardo has Serial1. You don't need to use SoftwareSerial

Answer (score 1):

I GOT IT!! It was problem with the pin settings.

According to SoftwareSerial library documentation, only pins 8,9,10,11,14,15,16 can be used for RX pin. But i used pin 4 for RX.